# Flashdata only shows every OTHER time the code runs

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I am relatively new to CodeIgniter, so I'm not sure if this is just bad coding, or if it is a problem with how I'm using CodeIgniter's flash data. For context: the user submits a phrase in a simple HTML form. The phrase is compared against what should be typed in (pretty simple, right?). This correct phrase changes based upon what step in the activity they are on. When they get the text wrong, I am attempting to use flashdata to show the error message. Here are the controller portions, followed by the view:

```
//Get step number
$step = $this->input->post('step');
$correct_text = array(
1 => 'TESTPHRASE',...
...

//If user enters the correct text           
$entered_text = strtoupper($this->input->post('entered_text'));
        if ($entered_text == $correct_text[$step]) 
        {   
            ...
        }
        //If user enters the incorrect text
        else 
        {
                $data['step'] = $step;
                $this->session->set_flashdata('entry_error', '<b>Sorry!</b>Your entry was incorrect. Be sure to carefully read the instructions!');
                $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }
```

Here is the view that only runs every **other** time.

```
<?php 
if ($this->session->flashdata('entry_error'))
{ ?>
   <div id="game_error">
   <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('entry_error'); ?>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html): CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared.

You are setting the flashdata and then trying to access it during the same request.  It's not available until the next request which is why it seems like it's only working every other time.

Comment: This is the next server request. The process is: controller calls "template.php" which also loads "entry.php" where the error is displayed. If there were a problem with one view calling another, why would the flashdata show at all?

Comment: You're setting the flashdata then loading `template.php` right after.  `template.php` is then loading `entry.php`.  This all happens during the same request.  Loading a view from another view does not make another request, it's all done on the server.

Comment: An example usage of flashdata could be logging the user in, setting the flashdata, and then redirecting them to some other page.  When they reached the final page they would be presented with a welcome message that was stored in the flashdata.  Subsequent page loads wouldn't display the welcome message.

Comment: BTW: I decided to just do the error message as a simple variable instead.

Comment: @blackairplane: If you `redirect()` to `current_url()` after setting the flashdata it will work, just move your `load->view()` to the last line and make sure to check if post data exists at all before running the `if` block. In any case, setting the variable will work fine too, as you have decided to do.